# How do I solve the integral: $\int \frac{dx}{[x(x^4-4)^\frac{1}{2} ]}$ using substitution method?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I was asked to solve the integral $$\int \frac{dx}{x(x^4-4)^\frac{1}{2}}$$ by using substitution. I've tried many values but none comes to work. I also tried factoring $x^4$ into $x^2\cdot x^2$ in order to try using trigonometric substitution but I could not go anywhere with $\sqrt{x^2\cdot x^2-4}$ . I have no clue what should I do.

I am new to this forum so I am sorry if I broke a rule.

Comment: You may try to let $y=\left(x^4-4\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is quite tricky, involving multiple substitutions.

Let $u=x^4-4$. Then $du=4x^3\,dx=\implies dx=\frac{du}{4x^3}$. Substituting that into the integral gives:
\begin{align*}\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4-4}} &=\int\frac{du}{4x^3(x)\sqrt u} \\
&=\int\frac{du}{4(u+4)\sqrt u} \\
&=\frac14\int\frac{du}{(u+4)\sqrt u}.\end{align*}
Now, let $v=\frac{\sqrt{u}}2$. This gives $\displaystyle\int\frac1{v^2+1}$, which is $\arctan(v)$. We substitute back all the variables to get $\boxed{\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}2\right)}4+C}$. I skipped some intermediate steps, but you should be able to figure them out.

Once you have more experience with these types of problems, you'll gain "intuition" on what to substitute.

Comment: how did you get that $2$ in the denominator when doing the substitution? I can't find it anyhere in the integrand.

Comment: Are you asking about $v=\frac{\sqrt u}2$?

Comment: Yes, that one. I still cannot figure out how'd you come out with that substitution.

Comment: Well because it reduces the nasty denominator to a standard integral. As I said, the more problems you do the more obvious the substitutions become.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $t=\frac 2{x^2}$. Then
$$\frac{dx}x=-\frac{dt}{2t},\>\>\>\>\> \frac1{\sqrt{x^4-1}}=\frac t{2\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
and
$$\int \frac{d x}{x \sqrt{x^4-4}}=-\frac14\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=-\frac14\sin^{-1}t+C
$$

Comment: I have no idea how you get from $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4-4}}$ to $-\dfrac14\displaystyle\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$. I mean, I understand you are performing a substitution, but how does the first equate to the latter?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @bobeyt6 - I added some details.

Comment: Ah, I see. Note that this answer is equivalent to all of the other answers, as they are essentially the same function, but with different constants.

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS:**
You start from $$I=\int \frac{dx}{x(x^4-4)^\frac{1}{2}}$$
You mentioned that you want a trigonometric substitution (things like sine and cosine). So you would need to transform your square root into something like $\sqrt{1-t^2}$. How to do this? Take $x^4$ as a factor in the square root.
Then $$I=\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4\left(1-\frac4{x^4}\right)}}=\int\frac{dx}{x^3\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2}{x^2}\right)^2}}$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$I = \int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^4 - 4}}
= \frac 12 \int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{\frac {x^4}4 - 1}}$

If $\frac{x^4}4$ were equal to $\sec^2 θ$,  we could have simplified the square root as $\tan θ$.

So let's substitute $x = \sqrt{2\sec θ}$ and proceed...

> Then we get $dx = \frac1{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{\sec θ} \tanθ \ dθ $

> $I = \frac12 \int \frac{\sqrt{\sec θ}\tanθ \ dθ}{\sqrt2\sqrt{2 \secθ} \tanθ} \\ = \frac 14 \int dθ \\ = \frac θ4 \\  = \frac14 \sec^{-1}(\frac {x^2}2) \\ = \frac14 \cos^{-1}(\frac 2{x^2}) + \color{grey}{c}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{x \sqrt{x^4-4}}&=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{x^4} d\left(\sqrt{x^4-4}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d\left(\sqrt{x^4-4}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^4-4}\right)^2+4} \\
&=\frac{1}{4} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^4-4}}{2}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$